# Alternate for CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION in gnuTLS

Tags: linux, curl, gnutls

I am using `CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION` in my program and gnuTLS as backend SSL in Linux.

As this CURL option is not supported in gnuTLS am getting `CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN` error.

Is there any alternate option available for “`CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION” in gnuTLS` ? If not available how to proceed ??

Comment: You should show the relevant code, where you are setting the specific context options. The options will help provide you with equivalent functionality.

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt(Config->hHandle->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION, *SSLCallBackFunction)` ... SSLCallBackFunction is function which i defined. In SSLCallBackFunction, we load Client Certificate, Key and Server CA Certificate in to SSL context(SSL_CTX_DATA) and function in to SSL_CTX_FUNCTION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no alternative option for this in libcurl. This feature has not been implemented for the GnuTLS backend.

The curl project welcome patches that changes this situation!